# Scala: Error in += for ArrayBuffer inside function

Tags: scala

I get error while append values to an `ArrayBuffer` in Scala. Given below the code :

```
def test()
  : (String,ArrayBuffer[(String,String,String)])
{
  val outstr=mutable.ArrayBuffer[(String,String,String)]()

  val testnmae="TESTING"
  val t=("A1","B1","C1");
  val t2=("A2","B2","C2");
  val t3=("A3","B3","C3");
  outstr += t;
<console>:9: error: illegal start of declaration (possible cause: missing `=' in front of current method body)
   outstr :+= t;
   ^
```

But do not get error while do same in REPL :

```
scala> val t=("A1","B1","C1");
t: (String, String, String) = (A1,B1,C1)
outstr += t;
res34: outstr.type = ArrayBuffer((A1,B1,C1))
```

Comment: scala shell prompt

Comment: I mean how you defined `outstr` in REPL?

Answer (score 0):

It's right there:

> `(possible cause: missing '=' in front of current method body)`

Add a `=` before the method body.

Another note: Consider using `ArrayBuffer.empty[(String, String, String)]` instead of calling the `apply` function with no parameters, it is perhaps a little cleaner.